# NativeCommandFailed, and I am using import zipfile in python 3.11.1

Tags: python, powershell

```
import zipfile

# Path to the zipped file
zip_file_path = r'C:\Ericsson\BigSnapshot\cwzdml_blt.zip'
```

```
PS C:\Users\alimoh5> & C:/Users/alimoh5/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Samsung/QCAlgo_Analysis/03072024/import zipfile.py"
Program 'python.exe' failed to run: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administratorAt line:1 char:1
+ & C:/Users/alimoh5/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ & C:/Users/alimoh5/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I tried to install zipfile.py using PowerShell and no module name found

> PS C:\Users\alimoh5> py -m "
> C:\Users\alimoh5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
> import zipfile.py
> C:\Users\alimoh5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe:
> Error while finding module specification for '
> C:\Users\alimoh5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe'
> (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '
> C:\Users\alimoh5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python')